# why form fields won't set as dirty onSubmit ? React-Hook-Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hook-form

Ok guys what we usaully do is if user touched the input then we validate it and show the message. this is ok but when user click the submit then all the fields should set to dirty and all error message should be visible.
but this won't happen in my code

```js
  const methods = useForm<FormProps>({
    mode: 'onTouched',
    defaultValues: {
      ...user.data,
    },
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
  });

        <ColumnStack spacing={0}>
          <InputLabel>First Name</InputLabel>
          <Controller
            control={control}
            name='firstName'
            render={({ field, formState }) => (
              <TextField
                placeholder='Enter Your First Name'
                error={formState.dirtyFields.firstName && formState.errors.firstName.message}
                helperText={formState.dirtyFields.firstName && formState.errors.firstName.message}
                disabled={loading}
                {...field}
              />
            )}
          />
        </ColumnStack>
```

how should i fix this ?
when user click on submit all form fields won't set as dirty.
I  tried changing validation mode to 'onChange' , 'onSubmit' , 'all'
but none of them solved my problem

Comment: I currently have the same issue, did you find a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`setValue("fieldName", value, { shouldDirty: true })` when updating a form value

Comment: the submit its being handle by react hook form. ``` onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}``` how should i use this ? the onSubmit Function won't execute because of errors